# Generate a number sequence

Tags: numbers, large-data

Given a integer **N** (0 < N < 10^1000), find a minimum number **M** greater than **N**, **M**  has the same length with **N** and the sum of the digits are equal. if M not exists return -1

example:

N=134 , M=143,  // 1+3+4=1+4+3

N=020, M = 101, //2=1+1 it seems 0 can be added to make length equal

N=120, M = 201, //2=1+1

The question is a written test question today i did, I have no idea how to solve it in a huge scope of **N**.

Answer (score 0):

Represent the numbers as strings of digits. **N** and **M** are just two strings of equal length.

Let's number **N**'s digits as *N<sub>k</sub>*, where *N<sub>0</sub>* is the last (rightmost) digit.

Set *M<sub>0</sub>*  = *N<sub>0</sub>* - 1, *M<sub>1</sub>*  = *N<sub>1</sub>* + 1, *M<sub>i</sub>*  = *N<sub>i</sub>* otherwise. The sum of digits of **M** stays the same as in **N**, because you've just moved a 1 from one digit to another, but now **M** > **N**.

Of course, this trick does not work if *N<sub>0</sub>* = 0 or if *N<sub>1</sub>* = 9. In this case, shift to *N<sub>1</sub>* and *N<sub>2</sub>* to transfer a 1, etc.

As an exercise, prove that **M** created this way is really the smallest number satisfying the conditions. (Or disprove — I may be wrong, especially in the case of *N<sub>0</sub>* = 0, though I don't see where I'm wrong there.)